# Can I mount a disk from more than one os?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I'm quite hazy on what things like mounting a disk actually mean.

I've got three drives on my system. SSD1 which houses Ubuntu (20.04), HDD1 which is just a storage harddrive, and SSD2 which houses Windows 10.

I've got my OS's split to different drives so windows would stop trying to erase Ubuntu's boot and kill itself in the process.

Currently from Ubuntu I can see all three drives by going to "Other Locations" in the file explorer and access them from there. Readonly.
I don't think I need to access SSD2 from Ubuntu. I do want to be able to read and write HDD1 from Ubuntu though.

If I boot to windows it has access to HDD1 like normal and I can't even see SSD1 (to my knowledge).
How can I set this up so that I can have the hard drive be shared?

Comment: Yes. You've 1) got to mount the HDD in Linux; if you want that to happen with every boot, that requires editing /etc/fstab to make that happen with every boot 2) the HDD has to use a filesystem Linux can understand, such as NTFS or FAT32, and 3) the HDD cannot be formatted as the (now discontinued)  Windows Dynamic Disc https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/ldm.html and must instead be the Basic Disc normally created by Windows 10 and every Windows preceding version. You'd have  to go out of your way to make a disc Dynamic. Is the HDD a Dynamic or Basic Disc?

Comment: Sometimes the drive mounts as read only because it has a corrupt file system. Do a file system check (CHKDSK command) in Windows and let it repair any problems it finds. I had this exact issue with a USB stick mounting as read only in Ubuntu, with error messages in dmesg. But a chkdsk command in Windows automatically fixed the corruptions in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out what partitions you have.  Open the application launcher and type partition or disks.  From there find the disks you want and look for their UUIDs.  That is how the system identifies that partition.  There are other ways but that is the most standard. [image]
2. Now you need to open a terminal.  Go to Applications again and type terminal. Open it and type the following command to open the fstab file. Now add lines as needed to automatically read/write mount the drives/partitions you want. NOTE.  fstab needs an empty line at the end.  Hit the return key a few times after the last line and then save.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```
3. Now save and exit the file.
4. From the terminal mount all the drives.

   sudo mount -a

[Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-fstab-works-introduction-to-the-etc-fstab-file-on-linux) is a good introduction to fstab and mounting disks.